# Break a nested loop in python, breaks all the loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, break

**What i have**: two nested loops.

**What i want**: exit from the inner loop when a condition is satisfied, and continue the external loop

**PROBLEM**: The 'break' command break all the loops!!!

This is the code:

```
for path in paths:
    for edge in path:
       ...
       #some stuff here
       ...
       if condition==TRUE:
         break # i want exit from the inner loop and continue the external loop whit next path in paths list
```

The code above doesn't work, because the break command break all the loops, but i want to stop the inner loop and continue the external loop whit the next element path in the list paths.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**: THis is my complete function: The command break stop the two loops. Why?

```
def feasible_path(G,paths):
#G is a graph
#paths is a list of all path in G between two nodes
paths_to_remove=[]
lenght_paths=len(paths)

for i in range(0,lenght_paths-1,1):
    minCap=sys.maxint
    print 'selected:'
    print paths[i]
    index=0
    lenght_path=len(paths[i])

    for index in range(0,(lenght_path)-1,1):
        id_source=(paths[i])[index]
        id_target=(paths[i])[index+1]

        if G.has_edge(id_source,id_target,key=0):
            cap_edge=G[id_source][id_target][0]['capacity']
            if(cap_edge<minCap):
                minCap=cap_edge

        else: # edge mising
            paths_to_remove.append(paths[i])
            minCap=-1
            break   #i want stop the for index loop

    if(minCap != -1):
        index=0
        for index in range(0,len(paths[i])-1,1):
            id_source=(paths[i])[index]
            id_target=(paths[i])[index+1]
            if G.has_edge(id_source,id_target,key=0):
                old_capacity=G[id_source][id_target][0]['capacity']
                new_capacity=old_capacity-minCap
                G[id_source][id_target][0]['capacity']=new_capacity
                if(new_capacity==0):
                    G.remove_edge(id_source,id_target,key=0)


print 'path to remove'
print paths_to_remove
return paths
```

Comment: Could you please add some more code to make your question more clear?

Comment: No, that's not how `break` works, it only ends the immediate loop it's in. Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually recreates this issue.

Comment: make sure there are enough paths.
add a print after the break in the outer loop

Comment: `break` only breaks the innermost loop [on my machine](http://ideone.com/i5JLbr).

Comment: I edit my answer with the complete function.

Comment: If you want to loop over the elements in a list, just use:  `for path in paths:`  You are using range wrong, you are omitting the last element.

Answer (score 1):

```
paths = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [3, 4, 5],
]

for path in paths:
    print path
    for edge in path:
        print '\t', edge
        if edge==3:
            print 'break'
            break
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
    1
    2
    3
break
[3, 4, 5]
    3
break
```

Two breaks: Therefore the break stops only the inner loop.

Edit:
With your code and a minimal Graph (enough to test your code...):

```
import sys
class Graph():
    def __init__(self):
        self.edges = set()

    def has_edge(self, src, trgt, key):
        return src+trgt in self.edges

    def remove_edge(self, src, trgt):
        self.edges.remove(src+trgt)

    def add(self, edge):
        self.edges.add(edge)

G = Graph()
#G.add('ab')
G.add('bc')
G.add('cd')
G.add('bm')
G.add('mc')
G.add('bn')
G.add('nd')
paths=[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'm', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'n', 'd']]

paths_to_remove=[]
lenght_paths=len(paths)

for i in range(0,lenght_paths-1,1):
    minCap=sys.maxint
    print 'selected:'
    print paths[i]
    index=0
    lenght_path=len(paths[i])

    for index in range(0,(lenght_path)-1,1):
        id_source=(paths[i])[index]
        id_target=(paths[i])[index+1]

        if G.has_edge(id_source,id_target,key=0):
            cap_edge=G[id_source][id_target][0]['capacity']
            if(cap_edge<minCap):
            minCap=cap_edge

        else: # edge mising
            paths_to_remove.append(paths[i])
            minCap=-1
            break   #i want stop the for index loop

    if(minCap != -1):
        print 'minCap != -1'
        index=0
        for index in range(0,len(paths[i])-1,1):
            id_source=(paths[i])[index]
            id_target=(paths[i])[index+1]
            if G.has_edge(id_source,id_target,key=0):
                old_capacity=G[id_source][id_target][0]['capacity']
                new_capacity=old_capacity-minCap
                G[id_source][id_target][0]['capacity']=new_capacity
                if(new_capacity==0):
                    G.remove_edge(id_source,id_target,key=0)
```

The output:

```
selected:
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
selected:
['a', 'b', 'm', 'c', 'd']
```

--> Your problem is not the break...

Comment: I edit my question with the complete function. Why it doesn't work for me?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it took me a while to figure this out as well!  The following code prints:

```
path to remove
[]
```

The only modifications I made were to indent the code below the function's signature (the first line) and call it at the bottom! 
Functions don't run until they are called! LOL :)

```
def feasible_path(G,paths):
    #G is a graph
    #paths is a list of all path in G between two nodes
    paths_to_remove=[]
    lenght_paths=len(paths)

    for i in range(0,lenght_paths-1,1):
        minCap=sys.maxint
        print 'selected:'
        print paths[i]
        index=0
        lenght_path=len(paths[i])

        for index in range(0,(lenght_path)-1,1):
            id_source=(paths[i])[index]
            id_target=(paths[i])[index+1]

            if G.has_edge(id_source,id_target,key=0):
                cap_edge=G[id_source][id_target][0]['capacity']
                if(cap_edge<minCap):
                    minCap=cap_edge

            else: # edge mising
                paths_to_remove.append(paths[i])
                minCap=-1
                break   #i want stop the for index loop

        if(minCap != -1):
            index=0
            for index in range(0,len(paths[i])-1,1):
                id_source=(paths[i])[index]
                id_target=(paths[i])[index+1]
                if G.has_edge(id_source,id_target,key=0):
                    old_capacity=G[id_source][id_target][0]['capacity']
                    new_capacity=old_capacity-minCap
                    G[id_source][id_target][0]['capacity']=new_capacity
                    if(new_capacity==0):
                        G.remove_edge(id_source,id_target,key=0)

    print 'path to remove'
    print paths_to_remove
    return paths
feasible_path("",[])
```

Comment: please try paths=[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'm', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'n', 'd']] instead []